# ArrayList.remove(i) doesn't delete all objects as it should

Tags: java, list

I have a simple listview(recyclerView), where each list-item have a checkbox. All items that is checked should be deleted with this code:

```java
for(int i = 0; i<shopListItems.size(); i++) {
    if(shopListItems.get(i).isBought == 1) {
        shopListItems.remove(i);
    }
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't. If 10 items are checked, then only 7 of them will be deleted and I have to run the code again to delete the rest.

The code seems fine, but I really don't understand why it doesn't delete all of the checked, or all that are `(isBought == 1)`.

Comment: If you delete item 0, the old item 1 will move down to position 0 but your loop will skip it by continuing at position 1.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[remove(index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int)) not only delete the object but shift all the remaining objects left to close the gap. You need to iterate from the end of the list to the start

```
for(int i = shopListItems.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    if(shopListItems.get(i).isBought == 1){
        shopListItems.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that now. I didn't know about .remove shifts the objects!

Comment: @Muddz  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int) Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

Comment: @Yoda thanks for the link. Thats important to know !I didn't thought of that. Ofcourse when you remove something from a list, there will be gap and this gap has to be closed.

Comment: You shouldn't be removing items while iterating the list in the first place - use an `Iterator` with `Iterator#remove()`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the ways mentioned above, you can also do it in ascending order:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if(list.get(i).isBought == 1){
        list.remove(i--);
    }
}
```

There is another simple alternative if you are using Java 8:

```
list = list.stream()
        .filter(item -> item.isBought == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Reference: http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/

Answer (score 3):

Reverse your loop!

```
        for(int i = shopListItems.size() -1; i >=0  i--){
            if(shopListItems.get(i).isBought == 1){
                shopListItems.remove(i);
            }
        }
```

If you are not intending to delete the entire ArrayList, you don't have to worry because, as the size changes, it will not effect the rest of the tests.